# Blackberry Event Handling and Focus Issues

Tags: blackberry

I am having an issue with a small blackberry application where touch events are being processed by 1 of 2 certain fields that has focus.

In my case, I have 2 images, one at the top (first element on the screen) and at the bottom (last element added to the screen.  Both are subclasses of the BitmapField.  Their purpose is to display a web site when the user taps (clicks with the trackpad/ball).

The issue is when either of these has focus, no matter where the user taps on the screen (i.e. in an EditField, another custom button, or just a part of the background), the BitmapField that has focus consumes the event calls the web browser.  This obviously only an issue on the BB Torch simulator, and I building for BB OS 5.0.

I have the BitmapField consuming both navigation clicks and touch events.

Also, any direction on where to get a good (as in not written by RIM) event handling guide for the Blackberry API would be helpful.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried:

```
    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return false;
    }
```

But, ideally I would like this to work on devices such as the Curve and Bold.

**UPDATE 2:**
There a couple of LabelFields inside layout managers that can receive focus, but they do not cause this issue, it only happens when the BitmapFields have focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to create a custom image button field by subclassing from `Field`. Override `paint(Graphics graphics)` to draw image and focused border (or background). Then just override `navigationClick(int status, int time)`. The BB UI framework will call that method when user clicks your field on a touch screen. As well it'll work for a non-touch screen devices. As a great benefit - you will not need to bother yourself with `TouchEvent`s at all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that on the `touchEvent()` you are checking the location of the touch. If it is outside of your BitmapField's extent, you should be returning `super.touchEvent(message)`. Regardless of where the touch is, when a field has focus it is sent to it first to determine if it should be handling it at all.